# Suggestions for keeping duplicate elements at equal length from middle in a linked list

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl, linked-list

I am processing a text document in C++ and for some parsing the linked list consists of duplicate elements as "words" of the document.

Now, I need an algorithm to sort this linked list such that the duplicate elements are at equal distance from middle but in opposite direction. The middle element is a MARK element.

```
Original Linked List:-
Head-> A-B-A-C-C-D-E-F-E-F-D-B (Size 12)

Processed Linked List:-
Head-> A-B-C-D-E-F-MARK-F-E-D-C-B-A (Size 13 = 12 + MARK)
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Will the elements are duplicated exactly once?

Comment: @asifsid88 Yes, in this case.

Comment: just have a wrapper that for index greater than that of mark returns item at mark - (idx - mark)

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl Cool interface solution, but I will need a processed list as output.

Answer (score 0):

If there are a even number, you can sort the list by value, and creating a new list of size+1, add MARK in the center.

Then:

```
//Iterate over the list, but process both the original and the duplicate at the same time.
for(i = 0; i < (original_list.size()/2); i++)
{
    //First element
    new_list[i] = original_list[i*2]

    //Duplicate element
    new_list[new_list.size() - i] = original_list[(i*2)+1]
}
```

Comment: If this is a std::list, operator[](int) isn't a valid member method.

Answer (score 0):

If the elements are duplicated **atleast once**. Then you may use the below algorithm
The complexity of the algorithm is O(n) but the insertion of nodes in new linked list will be O(nlogn)
Parse the linked list in every pass unplug the current node from the linkedList and add them to two new linkedlist (one in ascending order and other in descending order) and in the end add new node "MARK" to the end of the ascending linked list and now join the two newly created list.
HashMap is used to process only unique values (means not considering the duplicates)

Below is the JAVA code for the same, I apologize that I cannot provide the code in C++ (as I do not know C++ :P)
But I have tried to provide as much comments as I could so that you can get an idea
I have considered the list as Double Linked List with head and tail
Node has the following structure

```
class Node
{
  String data;
  Node next, prev;
}
```

The following code has the required methods and the sort function to create the processed linked list

```
public Node getHead()
{
    return this.head;
}

public void setHead(Node n)
{
    this.head = n;
}

public Node getTail()
{
    return this.tail;
}

public void setTail(Node n)
{
    this.tail = n;
}

public void addLast(Node n)
{
    // Adds the node to the last of the list
    // in such a way that the inserted node will
    // be sorted in increasing order
}

public void addFirst(Node n)
{
        // Adds the node to the first of the list
        // in such a way that the inserted node will
        // be sorted in non-increasing order
}

public Node sort(Node head)
{
    Node n = head;
    HashMap<String, Boolean> map = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
    LinkedList asc = new LinkedList();
    LinkedList des = new LinkedList();

    // Parse the linked list
    while(n!=null)
    {
    if(!map.containsKey(n.data))
    {
            // Remove the n from the Current Linked List
        delete(n);
        map.put(n.data);

        // Add in the new linked List
            asc.addLast(n);
            desc.addFirst(n);

            n = n.next;
    }
    }

    // Add new Node Mark to the end of the asc list
    asc.addLast(new Node("MARK"));

    // Join asc list to the desc list
    asc.getTail().next = desc.getHead();

    // Making head and tail as null as it is now combined with ASC list
    // If you do not do it then it may leads to memory leak
    // in deletion of nodes from processed list
    desc.setHead(null);
    desc.setTail(null);

    // Return the head of new processed list
    return asc.getHead();
}

public void delete(Node n)
{
    if(n==null)
        return;

    if(head==n)
    {
        // If the node to delete is head
        head = head.next;
    }
    else if(head==null)
    {
        // If the node to delete is tail
        tail = tail.prev;
    }
    else
    {
        // If the node to delete is present in the middle
        n.prev.next = n.next;
        n.next.prev = n.prev;
    }
    n.next = n.prev = null;
}
```

**NOTE**
If the values are not duplicated then it will create duplicate element, as each node is added into two linkedlist which is in the end merged

Comment: This cannot possibly be O(n) as it contains a comparison sort, which cannot be faster than O(n log n). From the two while loops in sort it appears to be O(n²).

Comment: Oopss!! My Bad.. Bymistake.. @svk Thanks :)

Comment: @svk I have changed my approach. Which is better than O(n^2)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all elements in the list are duplicated exactly once, you can use this approach.

```
#include <list>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char data[] = {'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'E', 'F', 'D', 'B'};
    std::list<char> c( data, data + sizeof(data) / sizeof(char) );

    // Remove all duplicates
    c.sort();
    std::list<char>::iterator i = std::unique( c.begin(), c.end() );
    c.resize( std::distance(c.begin(), i) );

    // Add 'M' (or MARK, if we were using strings).
    c.push_back( 'M' );

    // Add all the elements excluding 'M' to the back of the list.
    std::copy( ++c.rbegin(), c.rend(), std::back_inserter(c) );

    return 0;
}
```

You haven't given the expectation for the output if some elements are not duplicated.  So, I can't provide the right behavior for that case.  The approach can be made O(n) by using std::unordered_set (C++11) or some other hash set (e.g. stdext::hash_set by Dinkum).